Issue with Firebase App Distribution API - "Request contains an invalid argument" Error
I’m trying to use the Firebase App Distribution API to retrieve release information for my app, but I keep encountering a "Request contains an invalid argument" error.
Project Details:
    Project ID: testo-ea214
    App ID: 1:702746187202:android:408e8617b41fd4b098725b
    

The Firebase App Distribution API is enabled in the Google Cloud Console.
I am using a service account with the required permissions (firebase.appdistro.admin, firebase.sdk.admin, etc.).
Authentication:
I use gcloud auth print-access-token --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase to generate an access token.
The token seems valid, as I can make other successful API calls (e.g., listing Android apps).
I’m trying to retrieve the release information using the following curl command:
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testo-ea214/apps/1:702746187202:android:408e8617b41fd4b098725b/releases"


Error:
The response I receive is:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}


What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the App ID and Project ID are correct using gcloud commands and API calls.

curl -X GET "https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/androidApps" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"

{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "projects/testo-ea214/androidApps/1:702746187202:android:408e8617b41fd4b098725b",
      "appId": "1:702746187202:android:408e8617b41fd4b098725b",
      "displayName": "testo",
      "projectId": "testo-ea214",
      "packageName": "com.bitbar.testdroid",
      "apiKeyId": "6e72986b-0f0b-4247-8c55-121adbae8357",
      "state": "ACTIVE",
      "expireTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "etag": "1_9d509216-b647-44a0-b029-52b0eeff04f5"
    }
]
}


Checked IAM roles and permissions for the service account being used.
Double-checked that the Firebase App Distribution API is enabled in the Google Cloud Console.

Despite these steps, I am still encountering the same error. I’ve also tried different API versions (v1, v1beta1) but haven’t had any success.
